# How to use 'myLayout.addView(View v)' inside onPostExecute method in AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-studio

What should I do to add new TextViews (with text "inf1" and "inf2" from the code) into an existing linear layout from onPostExecute method in AsyncTask?

```
    protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
        String inf1="";
        String inf2="";
    try {

        JSONObject jsonObject =new JSONObject(response);
        JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray("result");


        for(int x=0; x < result.length(); x++) {
            JSONObject collegeData = result.getJSONObject(x);
            inf1 = collegeData.getString("title");
            inf2 = collegeData.getString("text");

            // Here I want to put these "inf1" and "inf2 strings into
            // textviews and add these textviews into an existing linear layout
            // with id: feedFetch"               

        }


    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

Comment: Your linear layout should have an `addView(...)` method so you can instantiate a few textviews and add them to it from `onPostExecute()`. This however seems like something you should be using a [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview) for.

Answer (score 0):

Find the view then add your child views to it:

```
    LinearLayout layout_named_feedFetch=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.feedFetch);
    //or call the_parent_view_of_feedFetch.findViewById() if it's the child another view; 
    for(int x=0; x < result.length(); x++) {
        JSONObject collegeData = result.getJSONObject(x);
        inf1 = collegeData.getString("title");
        inf2 = collegeData.getString("text");
        //create the new views
        TextView tv=new TextView(getApplicationContext());
        //add them to where you want
        layout_named_feedFetch.addView(tv);
        //assign values to them
        tv.setText(inf1+" "+inf2);
    }
```